# Why can I create cast operator to every class except self

Tags: c++

```
struct B 
{

};

struct A
{
    operator A&() const;
    operator B&() const;
};


int main()
{
    const A a;
    B& br = a;
    A& ar = a;  
}
```

Why can I create cast operator to `B&`, but not to `A&`.

May be it does not have much sense (one can use it to erase `const` modifier, as in example), but it at least inconsistent!

Comment: why do you want to cast self to self ?

Comment: @Andrew, to remove `const`, as I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, a convenient way to trigger undefined behavior. Why would you want something like this?

Comment: there is a const_cast for that

Comment: `const_cast` does not allow you do 'smart' const removal

Comment: What exactly is "smart" const removal? I always thought that const is const, and either something is const or it isn't. Why do you need anything smarter than `const_cast`?

Comment: The cast operator to self is called "constructor". If you want some sort of "smart" const removal, I guess what you mean is getting a non-const copy of the const instance (because for anything else you have const_cast). Just add a A copy() const; method.

Comment: You said it yourself: it doesn't make sense. That's why it's not allowed. It conflicts too much with the existing semantics of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this because it's explicitly forbidden. N3290 § 12.3.2 states:

> Such functions are called
>   conversion functions. No return type can be specified. If a conversion function is a member function, the
>   type of the conversion function (8.3.5) is “function taking no parameter returning conversion-type-id”. **A
>   conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly cv-qualified) object to the (possibly cv-qualified)
>   same object type (or a reference to it)**, to a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of that type (or a reference to
>   it), or to (possibly cv-qualified) void.

(Emphasis mine)

This is discussed further in a note:

> These conversions are considered as standard conversions for the purposes of overload resolution (13.3.3.1, 13.3.3.1.4) and
>   therefore initialization (8.5) and explicit casts (5.2.9).

Which explains this decision - it would interfere with the built-in mechanics too much. (For little gain).

If you really want something non-`const` from a `const` object the only smart way to do this is constructing a new instance using the copy constructor.

As a work around you could introduce a lightweight intermediary (like a smart pointer):

```
struct B {};

struct A {};

namespace {
  B b_inst;
  A a_inst;
}

struct A_wrapper {
  A& inst;
  // This is perfectly fine: const alters the reference, not what it refers to
  operator A&() const { return inst; }
  operator B&() const { return b_inst; }
  A_wrapper() : inst(a_inst) {}
};

int main() {
  const A_wrapper a;
  B& br = a;
  A& ar = a;
}
```

But really, wanting to do this in the first place looks like a code smell.

Comment: Very nice. I really couldn't find those quotes.

Comment: @pmr - it's in "Special member functions", not "Overloading"

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do this would be to use [const_cast](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/keyword_const_cast.htm).

For example,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(int* p) {
  cout << *p << endl;
}

int main(void) {
  const int a = 10;
  const int* b = &a;

  // Function f() expects int*, not const int*
  //   f(b);
  int* c = const_cast<int*>(b);
  f(c);

  // Lvalue is const
  //  *b = 20;

  // Undefined behavior
  //  *c = 30;

  int a1 = 40;
  const int* b1 = &a1;
  int* c1 = const_cast<int*>(b1);

  // Integer a1, the object referred to by c1, has
  // not been declared const
  *c1 = 50;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know, what `const_cast` does. And I know its _limitations_.

Comment: @Lol4t0: You can add or remove `const`. What limitations are you referring to?

Comment: @Lol4t0: looks like you are writing const just to violate it )

Comment: The question was not 'how to cast away `const`' but 'why _this_ does not work'. That is why it is not the _answer_.

Comment: @Lol4t0: I'm not sure I understand.  In your example in the comment above, are you trying to change the value of 10 to 30?

Comment: @andand: He wants to remove the constness forever and ever, but that ain't gonna happen.

Answer (score 3):

Declaring a conversion to a reference to self is not ill-formed. Your problem comes at the time where your reference is initialized. As the type of the reference and the type of the initialization expression are the same, the reference is `bound directly` and your user defined conversion operator is never considered. Thus normal conversion rules apply and const conversion makes the code ill-formed.

Anyway, what your are doing is basically asking yourself to get shot in the foot. If you don't like `constness`, **don't use it**. If you do it consistently, it will never bother you, but it is not going to make you new friends.